# Ext Js 4 gmappanel change center dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extjs

I've a simple gmappanel (extjs 4.1.1).
How to change the "center" of the map and refresh my window with the center in new coordinate?

My code is:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
        enabled : true
    });
Ext.require(['Ext.window.*', 'Ext.ux.GMapPanel']);

Ext.define('AM.view.gmapwindow.GoogleMap', {
extend : 'Ext.window.Window',
alias : 'widget.gmapw',
autoShow : true,
title : 'map',
closeAction : 'hide',
width : 460,
height : 500,
border : false,
x : 40,
y : 60,
items : [{
            layout : {
                type : 'hbox',
                align : 'stretch'
            },
            flex : 1,
            items : [{
                        xtype : 'textfield'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'button',
                         handler: function() {
//--------------------
//modify here the center 
//geoCodeAddr:'Suisse Romande, Avenue de la Gare, Sion, Svizzera'
//---------------------
                            }
                    }]
        }, {
            width : 450,
            layout : 'fit',
            height : 450,
            border : false,
            items : {
                xtype : 'gmappanel',
                center : {
                    geoCodeAddr : '4 Yawkey Way, Boston, MA, 02215-3409, USA'

                },

                markers : []
            }
        }]
```

});

the map is well shown, but if i try to change the center editing

> geoCodeAddr

with the following code

```
this.up('gmapw').down('gmappanel').center.geoCodeAddr='Suisse Romande, Avenue de la Gare, Sion, Svizzera';
```

nothing happens.

any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [GMapPanel.js](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/extjs-build/examples/ux/GMapPanel.js), you will see that in `afterFirstLayout()`, `geoCodeAddr` is used when creating the map. Setting it after layout is not going to do anything since `afterFirstLayout()` won't be called again.

You should geocode your address and use that to set the center on the map. Something like the following should work:

```
var map = this.gmap;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var request = {address: 'Suisse Romande, Avenue de la Gare, Sion, Svizzera'};
var callBack = function(geocoderResults, geocoderStatus) {
    if(geocoderStatus === 'OK') {
        var location = geocoderResults[0].geometry.location;
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat(), location.lng());
        map.setCenter(latLng);
    }
}
geocoder.geocode(request,callBack);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modify Arun V answer to make it full working for my example.

Thank you again Arun V:

```
var request = {address: 'Suisse Romande, Avenue de la Gare, Sion, Svizzera'};
var callBack = function(geocoderResults, geocoderStatus) {
    if(geocoderStatus === 'OK') {
        var location = geocoderResults[0].geometry.location;
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat(), location.lng());
        //get current Id from document useful if you have more than one map
        //you can't use "this.gmap" reference here because it's not in your scope
        var idMapW = this.document.activeElement.id;
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#'+idMapW)[0].down('gmappanel').gmap.setCenter(latLng);
        }
    };
    this.up('gmapw').down('gmappanel').geocoder.geocode(request,callBack);
```